# Sequence defined by $s_{n+1}=\sqrt{s_{n}s_{n+2}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $(s_n)$ be the sequence defined by:
>   $$  s_0,s_1\in \mathbb{R}^{+},\quad \forall n\in \mathbb{N};\quad s_{n+1}=\sqrt{s_{n}s_{n+2}}  $$
>
> 1. $(s_n)$ is arithmetic sequence
> 2. $(s_n)$ is geometric sequence
> 3. $(s_n)$ is neither arithmetic nor geometric
> 4. we can not conclude anything

note that from french source $\mathbb{R}^{+}=\{x\in R \mid x \geq 0\}$ which means $0 \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ so here we talk about $0\in\mathbb{R}^{+}$

**My thoughts:**

first if $s_0=0, s_1=1$ then $1=0$ is undefined so let take   $s_0,s_1\in \mathbb{R}^{+}_{*}=\{x \mid x  \text{is a strictly positive real number} \}$

and let 's check every suggestions:

1. Yes, indeed:
   If $s_0=0$, else, $s_{n+1}=b$, $s_n=b-r$ and $ s_{n+2}=b+r$ implies 
   $b=\sqrt{b^2-r^2}$, thus the conclusion : $r=0$.
2. Yes, indeed:
   for all $n, \frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n}=q>0$ and $q\ne 1$ (for example by induction on $n$).
3. nope from solution of question 1 and 2
4. nope of course!

Am i right is there other nice proofs.

**Add some thoughts :**

if $s_{0}=s_{1}$ then $(s_n)$ is a constant sequence and by that we know that it's an arithmetic sequence with ratio equal $0$ and it's a geometric sequence with an common ratio equal $1$

then answer $1$ and $2$ are both correct

-**I would to prove also** that others suggestions are worng so Correct that if i am wrong please :

here is my tired

- If $s_{0}=0$ then $s_{n}=s_{n+1}$ so the sequence $v_{n}$ is constant and thus :

  $A$) True $B$) True $C$) False $D$) false
- If $s_{0}\neq 0$ then

  $$
  \begin{align*}\forall n\in \mathbb{N};\quad s_{n+1}=\sqrt{s_{n}s_{n+2}}
   &\Longleftrightarrow s^{2}_{n+1}={s_{n}s_{n+2}} \\
  & \Longleftrightarrow \frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n} = \frac{s_{n+2}}{s_{n+1}}\\
  &\Longleftrightarrow S_{n} \text{ is geometric }
  \end{align*}
  $$
  and thus : $A$) False  $B$) true  $C$) False $D$) False

Comment: what is $v_n$? by the way, if $s_0=0$ then the sequence $s_n=0$ is constant in any way

Answer (score 3):

Note that

$$s_{n+1}^2 = s_ns_{n+2}$$
$$\frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n} = \frac{s_{n+2}}{s_{n+1}}$$

The ratio between any term and the preceding one remains the same hence it must be a geometric progression.

---

...unless the common ratio is equals to one, in which case all terms in the sequence are equal.

Comment: but how did you know that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N},\quad s_n,s_{n+1}\neq 0$

Comment: as i know $x\in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ means x can take $0$ but if $x\in \mathbb{R}^{+}_{*}$ then  we have definitly $x\neq 0$

Comment: @Educ Note that $s_0 \not=0$. Any positive power of a non-zero number is non-zero, and since every term can be written as a product of the first term with some power of the common ratio, they must be non-zer0.

Comment: @Educ By definition, $\mathbb{R}^+$ does not contain $0$.

Comment: nope i don't think so $\mathbb{R}^+= \{x \in \mathbb R : x \geq 0\}=[0,+\infty) $ but $\mathbb{R}^++=\mathbb{R}^{+}_{*}= \{x \in \mathbb R : x  >  0 : is a strictly positive real number \}=(0,+\infty) $ which means $0\neq \mathbb{R}^{++} $

Comment: @Educ I believe it is a widely adopted convention/definition that $\mathbb{R}$ contains all positive real numbers, and that $0$ is non-positive. It would be a good idea to clarify with the source of the question for its convention\definition for $\mathbb{R}^+$.

Answer (score 1):

If you rewrite the recursion as $s_{n+1}=s_n^2/s_{n-1}$ and take logarithms, you get a recursion

$$t_{n+1}=\log s_{n+1}=2\log s_n-\log s_{n-1}=2t_n-t_{n-1}$$

The recursion in $t_n$ has the generic solution

$$t_n=An+B$$

hence

$$s_n=e^{An+B}=Cr^n\quad\text{with } C=e^B\text{ and }r=e^A$$

which is a geometric sequence.

Comment: could you point to some  source wich offer that  method

Comment: @Educ, the theory of linear recurrence equations is well developed in many places, especially the theory for two-term recurrence, which depends on little more than solving a quadratic equation.  It almost always makes sense to try to express a recurrence with the "next" term in terms of previous terms, and it almost always makes sense to linearize things when possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if   $s_0,s_1\in \mathbb{R}^{+},\quad \forall n\in \mathbb{N};\quad s_{n+1}=\sqrt{s_{n}s_{n+1}}$, you can simplify by $\sqrt{s_{n+1}}$, then square both sides, to find $s_{n+1}=s_n$, which seems rather strange. I think there's a typo, and that we should read $s_0,s_1\in \mathbb{R}^{+},\quad \forall n\in \mathbb{N^{*}};\quad s_{n+1}=\sqrt{s_{n}s_{n-1}}$
If we use that definition, then the sequence is neither arithmetic nor geometric in general, but if $s_0=s_1$, it trivially is both.

Comment: sorry there was typo :  $s_{n+1}=\sqrt{s_{n}s_{n+2}} $